# SMQP: differences between AMQP and JMS

Tags: java, jms, messaging, amqp

I am looking for some information about the messaging protocol SMQP (Simple Message Queue Protocol). I have not been able to find much on the internet so I decided to ask here because somebody may know:

```
1) What are the main differences between SMQP and AMQP protocols?
2) What are the main differences between SMQP and JMS protocols? 
3) Is SMQP based on JMS? If so, can a standard JMS implementation be used?
4) Is there any open source implementation of the SMQP protocol for Java?
5) Is this protocol being used anywhere?
```

I would appreciate references to information if you have some also.

Thanks for the help!